# How can I generate a piped NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I was intercepting AJAX request in `cachedResponseForRequest:`, and then construct a custom Response for the request. But it seems that this API method always work on a same thread, so if I was doing a time consuming operation, new requests would be blocked. In `Android`, I solved this problem using PipedStream, But `cachedResponseForRequest:` returns response with `NSData`, How can I make NSData pipable, can anybody help me out

Here is My Code:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSURL *url=request.URL;
    NSCachedURLResponse *response=nil;
    if([url.path containsString:@"aa1"]){
        NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData data];
        NSThread* asyncThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getData:) object:data];
        [asyncThread start];
        NSURLResponse *urlresponse=[[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:url MIMEType:@"application/json" expectedContentLength:data.length textEncodingName:@"utf-8"];
        response=[[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:urlresponse data:data];

    }
    return response;
}

-(void)getData:(NSMutableData*)data{
    NSMutableString *str=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    for(int i=0;i<1024*1024;i++){
        [str appendFormat:@"s"];
    }
    [data appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"%d",data.length);
}
```

And In android, I solved this matter like follow

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
            String url) {
    WebResourceResponse response = null;
    if (url.contains("loca/aa0")) {
        try {
            final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
            InputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        InputStream s = ctx.getAssets().open("s.txt");
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
                        while (s.read(buffer) != -1)
                            out.write(buffer);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            task.execute();
            response = new WebResourceResponse("application/html","UTF-8", in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

can anybody see my Question?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Here's my code

Comment: Have you read the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)?

Comment: @Mats I'm not familiar with this field , but for my condition, this URL won't get any response from server ,it's an AJAX request, and I need to intercept this request and generate a response for it